# WordPress: Custom Post Type, Send Data to "register_meta_box_cb" Arg

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding multiple custom post types to a WordPress website, and I'm trying to optimize the code by using variables and merging functions. I was able to send 2 variables to the `create_rma_project_post_type` function that used to `register_post_type`. I'd like to do the same thing with the argument that attaches the metabox creation function. The first code below works completely. It uses `register_meta_box_cb` to call `add_project_metaboxes`:

```
add_action('init', create_rma_project_post_type('project','our-people'));
function create_rma_project_post_type($post_type,$display_page) {
    $prefix = 'rma';
    $post_label = ucfirst($post_type);

    register_post_type($prefix.'_'.$post_type,
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( $post_label.'s' ),
                'singular_name' => __( $post_label ),
                'all_items' => __( $post_label.' List' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New '.$post_label),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New '.$post_label),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit '.$post_label),
                'new_item' => __( 'New '.$post_label),
                'view_item' => __( 'View '.$post_label),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search'),
                'parent_item_colon' => 'about-us/'.$display_page,
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'about-us/'.$display_page,'with_front' => false),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_project_metaboxes',
        )
    );
}

function add_project_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('rma_project_metabox_information', 'Project Information', 'rma_project_metabox_information_callback', 'rma_project', 'normal', 'default');
}
```

What I want to do is change the metabox call to send a variable, with the goal of being able to remove the "projects" word from the function, and use the one function for all custom post types.

This is what I'd like that line to read:

```
            'register_meta_box_cb' => add_project_metaboxes($post_type),
```

When I do that, it doesn't work. Neither do any of these:

```
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_project_metaboxes($post_type)',
            'register_meta_box_cb' => function(add_project_metaboxes($post_type)),
            'register_meta_box_cb' => function('add_project_metaboxes($post_type)'),
            'register_meta_box_cb' => sprintf( __('add_project_metaboxes(%s)'), $post_type ),
```

My first question is, is this possible currently with WordPress? If yes, how can I do that? Appreciate any help, and if you need clarification of anything please let me know.

---

## Edit 2017

Using this and other answers I created a set of helper classes to make CTP's easier to manage. If you'd like to see finished product, see:

https://gist.github.com/Kelderic/dc641aced67f0c0cb0a4a1ded17fa0d4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `register_meta_box_cb` callback has one input argument, namely the `WP_Post` object of the currently edited post.

So I think you should be able to get the post type from that object by using the `get_post_type()` WordPress function.

If you check out the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1324) for the `register_post_type()` you will find that it  contains this part:

```
 if ( $args->register_meta_box_cb )
     add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $args->register_meta_box_cb, 10, 1 );
```

So try to replace:

```
'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_project_metaboxes',
```

with:

```
'register_meta_box_cb' => 'custom_add_metaboxes',
```

where:

```
function custom_add_metaboxes( $post )
{

    // get the current post type
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post );

    // your logic for the add_meta_box code
    // ...

}
```

contains the logic based on the current post type.

**Update:**

> is a way to store/associate an array of data to a custom post type?

**a)** Yes, you can use the [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to store data associated to a custom post type with a given `$post_id`:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

where `$meta_value` can be a *string* or an *array*. For example:

```
update_post_meta( 38, 'my_data', array( 'somekey' => 'somevalue' ) );
```

To fetch the array data, you can use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
$data = get_post_meta( 38, 'my_data', FALSE );
```

**b)** If you want to store some data array, that's related to all posts in a given custom post types, you can use [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) to store it and [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to fetch it.

For example you can use:

```
$data = array( 
              'cpt1' => array( 'somekey1' => 'somevalue1' ),
              'cpt2' => array( 'somekey2' => 'somevalue2' ),
);

update_option( 'my_data', $data );
```

to store the `$data` array and

```
$data = get_option( 'my_data' );
```

to fetch it back.

--

Hope this help.

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't realize that the function called by `register_meta_box_cb` would be sent the `$post` automatically. By any chance to you know if there is a way to store/associate an array of data to a custom post type?

Comment: @AndyM I updated the answer, with an example how to store/associate an array of data to a custom post type. Hope this help.

Comment: Looks great, I'll be awarding you the bounty in 3 hours when it lets me.

Comment: @AndyM Thanks and best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

its not really a wordpress issue, more a question of how do functions get called when stored? if it is looking for a function name you need to give it as such.

I see what you are trying to do, if you want call add_project_metaboxes($post_type) just after you declare the array, add_meta_boxes used to be hooked to "init" so it may work. Btw...the function as it exists above won't work unless you modify it to take a parameter.

If not a OOP type object might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, yes and no. It's a question how does WordPress specifically call functions that are stored. Calling `add_project_metaboxes()` could be just called from inside `create_rma_project_post_type` possibly, though, now that you mention. I'll take a look. Could you clarify the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph, because everything in the first block of code works as is, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: yes, if you call add_project_metaboxes() will work but if you try and call add_project_metaboxes($var) you need to modify the function to take a variable. But you prob were doing this anyway!

Comment: Oh, yes. I would need to change all instances of `"project"` to `.$post_type.`, and put in a parameter to catch the sent data. That part isn't the issue.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, this doesn't actually answer my question, because putting a call to `add_project_metaboxes` inside the `create_rma_project_post_type` doesn't work. I'm going to place a bounty and see if I can get any other ideas. Feel free to edit your answer if you can think of anything.

Comment: add  add_action('init', 'add_project_metaboxes') into the function rma project function not the function itself. But see below for a class based solution which should make things a lot easier for mulitple new post types.

Answer (score 1):

im posting a base class i use for custom post types, its not my code and i can't remember where i picked it up but credit to the creator! it works really well for what i usually create custom posts for and it should work with your code (see below, i attempted quickly to reproduce your function). Hopefully it helps!

btw: you can store custom info for the post by using post_meta (you can pull this using the postid). let me know if this is unclear and ill do something in pastebin.

```
class base_posttype {

public $post_type_name;
public $post_type_variables;
public $post_type_labels;
public $meta_keys;
public $result= array();

public function __construct( $name, $variables= array(), $labels=array() ) {

     $this->post_type_name = $name ;
     $this->post_type_variables = $variables;
     $this->post_type_labels = $labels;


     if( ! post_type_exists ( $this-> post_type_name ) ){

        add_action ('init', array( &$this, 'register_post_type' ) );

     }

     $this->save();

} //------------end construct------------------------------------------


public function register_post_type() {

    $name       = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $this->post_type_name ) );
    $plural     = $name . 's';

    $labels = array_merge(

    // Default
    array(
        'name'                  => _x( $plural, 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( $name, 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'               => _x( 'Add New', strtolower( $name ) ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New ' . $name ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit ' . $name ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New ' . $name ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All ' . $plural ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View ' . $name ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search ' . $plural ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon'     => '',
        'menu_name'             => $plural
    ),


    $this->post_type_labels

    );


    $args = array_merge(


    array(
        'label'                 => $plural,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        '_builtin'              => false,
    ),

    // Given args
    $this->post_type_args

    );

    // Register the post type
    $this->result[]=register_post_type( $this->post_type_name, $args );    
}


/* attach the taxonomy to the post type */
public function add_taxonomy( $name, $args = array(), $labels = array() ) {

     if( ! empty( $name ) ) {
    $post_type_name = $this->post_type_name;

    // Taxonomy properties
    $taxonomy_name      = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $name ) );
    $taxonomy_labels    = $labels;
    $taxonomy_args      = $args;

    if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy_name ) ) {

    //Capitilize the words and make it plural
    $name       = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $name ) );
    $plural     = $name . 's';

    // Default labels, overwrite them with the given labels.
    $labels = array_merge(

    // Default
        array(
            'name'                  => _x( $plural, 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( $name, 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search ' . $plural ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All ' . $plural ),
            'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent ' . $name ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent ' . $name . ':' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit ' . $name ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update ' . $name ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New ' . $name ),
            'new_item_name'         => __( 'New ' . $name . ' Name' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( $name ),
    ),

        // Given labels
        $taxonomy_labels

    );

    // Default arguments, overwritten with the given arguments
    $args = array_merge(

    // Default
    array(
        'label'                 => $plural,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        '_builtin'              => false,
    ),

    // Given
    $taxonomy_args

    );

    // Add the taxonomy to the post type
    add_action( 'init', function() use( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args ) {
        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args );
        });

    } else {

        add_action( 'init', function() use( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name ) {
            register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name );
        });

    }


    }
}

/* Attaches meta boxes to the post type */
public function add_meta_box( $title, $fields = array(), $context = 'normal', $priority = 'default' ) {

    // We need to know the Post Type name again
    $post_type_name = $this->post_type_name;

    // Meta variables
    $box_id         = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $title ) );
    $box_title      = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $title ) );
    $box_context    = $context;
    $box_priority   = $priority;

    // Make the fields global
    global $custom_fields;
    $custom_fields[$title] = $fields;

    add_action( 'admin_init', function() use( $box_id, $box_title, $post_type_name, $box_context, $box_priority, $fields ) {

    add_meta_box( $box_id, $box_title, function( $post, $data ) {
            global $post;

            // Nonce field for some validation
            wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'custom_post_type' );

            // Get all inputs from $data
            $custom_fields = $data['args'][0];

            // Get the saved values
            $meta = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

            // Check the array and loop through it
            if( ! empty( $custom_fields ) ) {
                /* Loop through $custom_fields */
                foreach( $custom_fields as $label => $type ) {
                    $field_id_name  = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $data['id'] ) ) . '_' . strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $label ) );

                    echo '<label for="' . $field_id_name . '">' . $label . '</label><input type="text" name="custom_meta[' . $field_id_name . ']" id="' . $field_id_name . '" value="' . $meta[$field_id_name][0] . '" />';
                }
            }},
            $post_type_name,
            $box_context,
            $box_priority,
            array( $fields )
            );
        });

}



/* Listens for when the post type being saved */
public function save() {

       // Need the post type name again
$post_type_name = $this->post_type_name;

add_action( 'save_post', function() use( $post_type_name ) {
        // Deny the WordPress autosave function
        if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_post_type'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) ) return;

        global $post;

        if( isset( $_POST ) && isset( $post->ID ) && get_post_type( $post->ID ) == $post_type_name )
        {
            global $custom_fields;

            // Loop through each meta box
            foreach( $custom_fields as $title => $fields )
            {
                // Loop through all fields
                foreach( $fields as $label => $type )
                {
                    $field_id_name  = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $title ) ) . '_' . strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $label ) );

                    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_id_name, $_POST['custom_meta'][$field_id_name] );
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

and then you can create the post by using this class e.g.

```
 class project_post_type {

public function __construct () {


$project= new base_posttype ('project', array(
'has_archive' => TRUE,
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'our-people',
            'with_front' => FALSE,
        ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'menu_icon' => AD_URL . '/resources/img/adlogo.png'
    ));

    $project->add_taxonomy( 'location');
$project->add_taxonomy ('categories', array(
'hierarchical' => true
));

$project->add_meta_box( 'Project Info' , array(
    'price' => 'text',
    'condition' => 'text',
    'age' => 'text',
    'expiration_date' => 'text', // int
    'fee' => 'text',
    'discount' => 'text',
    'due' => 'text',
    'paid' => 'text',
    'sold' => 'text' //boolan
    )
);

}
}

$project= new project_post_type;
```

normally if i have a array of data i need to use for the post type, i set it within the class, so a method to pull the meta keys and a method to save, most of the time not necessary but on a few occasions where i have the likes of submit forms from the front end, it comes in handy.

Comment: This looks interesting but not as directly applicable as birgire's answer. I appreciate the help though, so +1!